# Where did Derrida say that Jonathan Culler's On Deconstruction is a good introduction to his work?

Tags: quote-source, theory, jacques-derrida, jonathan-culler

The works of the French philosopher [Jacques Derrida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Derrida) (1930 – 2004) had a significant impact on literary theory, leading to the development of a method of analysis known as [deconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction). (Derrida said deconstruction in his own writings did [not refer to a method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction#Not_a_method), but that is a different minefield.)

However, Derrida's work is difficult to read:

> I just read some Derrida and I gotta say...I feel ten times more stupid than when I started it. ([PhD student Shelby Carr on Twitter](https://twitter.com/CarrShelb/status/1172656925676310528), 14 September 2019).

For this reason, people try to find good introductions to Derrida. On a [Reddit thread from four years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/46u0vb/any_good_books_that_introduce_derrida/), somebody said (emphasis added),

> I have to say that the best book is Jonathon [sic] Culler's *On Deconstruction* - **it was the only book that Derrida himself said was a good introduction**.

The statement has no source, so I'm curious to know where Derrida said this.